# Virtual host in NGINX is not resolving

Tags: nginx, dns, virtualhost

1) Installed clean latest Debian on my raspberry pi-3-B
2) Installed NGINX
3) I have static wan IP adress 185.154.72.37
4) My hostname is cheekibreeki.asuscomm.com
5) Forwarded port 80 on my router to RSPI3B's lan static IP (192.168.1.35)
6) Placed web page on NGINX.
7) My friend succesfully opened the page using url: http://cheekibreeki.asuscomm.com
8) Created virtual host mf.cheekibreeki.asuscomm.com on NGINX using manual 
9) Placed another web page to the appropriate folder for host mf.cheekibreeki.asuscomm.com
10) Friend cannot open url http://mf.cheekibreeki.asuscomm.com/index.html, host cannot be resolved
What did I configure wrong?

Comment: You didn't configure DNS. And maybe it wouldn't be possible